# OSX - How to Wipe a SDCard

Tags: sd-card

I'm unable to erase an SDCard (32GB). I've installed NOOBS (Raspberry Pi) on it and run the installation on the device, which result as a files corruption. Well, now I would like to wipe it and retry the installation. I'm unable to do it. I've tried several commands (eraseDisk, sudo eraseDisk, eraseVolume, fdisk, gparted, etc.).

I'm unable to erase the disk (and volume) or replace the partition table.

Using the command : `sudo diskutil erasedisk exfat new /dev/disk2`

Gives me the error: `-69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed`

Comment: Do not cross post.

Comment: @Milliways If you notice a cross-post please include a link to it (this mitigates the major issue).  Our policy is ambiguous, although S.E. generally frowns on it and many exchanges explicitly forbid it.

Comment: @marren You should not need to bother erasing the card to put an image on it.  The image should overwrite what's there from the starting block.  If you are using OSX, use `dd` *on the device, not a partition of the device*. It doesn't matter whether it contains data that might be considered meaningful in some context or not.  You are creating an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).  The real issue is either the installation is not being done correctly or the card is defunct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried another SD-Card and/or Card-Reader and/or another Computer?
There are multiple reasons why you get this error:

- the SD-Card is faulty
- the Card-Reader is broken (I had that once and went mad until I found that error)
- there is a problem with your System

Nonetheless you can try

```
sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

to entirely wipe the card. This must work if everything is fine with your equipment.

`/dev/rdisk` provides raw access and is therefore faster than `/dev/disk`.